# Android App crashes on decimal point input to EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-spinner

I'm creating an Android app that takes in basic user input (from keyboard) via an `EditText` widget. I'm getting some stubborn behavior from a line I call within the `OnItemSelected` function for my `Activity`'s `Spinners`. I am gathering the double value from my `EditText` (doing appropriate type conversions), and the app crashes. My logcat's report that the error is that "" is not an appropriate `double` value, which means that this function is being called while the `EditText` is still empty (I'm guessing for the initial selection of the `Spinners` on creation of `Activity`). Android Studio is warning me of this possible exception on the call:

> Method invocation 'inputView.getText().toString()' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   This inspection reports those conditions in the specified inspection scope that are always true or false, as well as points out where a RuntimeException may be thrown, based on data flow analysis of the code. This inspection also reports Nullable/NotNull contract violations. Annotations to support the contract can be configured (by default @Nullable/@NotNull annotations from annotations.jar will be used)

I've appended my logcat message as well as one of the fishy code segments that is of the problem causing genre, bolding the relevant segments.

**LogCat**:

```
10-12 01:18:22.244    1148-1148/khandy.application.convertible E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
**java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""**
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
at **khandy.application.convertible.EntryActivity.onItemSelected(EntryActivity.java:160)**
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code segment:**

```
TextView resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView);
EditText inputView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.haveTextField);
factor = getFactorFromTable();
double input = Double.parseDouble(**inputView.getText().toString()**);
resultView.setText(Double.toString(input * factor));
```

Any ideas on how to fix and insight on why this happens? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure input or factor are not empty?

Answer (score 1):

> (I'm guessing for the initial selection of the spinners on creation of activity)

This is correct. `OnItemSelected()` is called when your `Activity` first starts. So if your `EditText` is empty at this point then you will get an exception.

> Any ideas on how to fix and insight on why this happens?

You have many options to circumvent this. You could either put a default value in there, say, 0.0, which you may not want to do depending on what your app does with the value. You could create a `boolean` flag as a member variable. Set this variable to `true` by default then change it to `false` in `onItemSelected()`. Then check in `onItemSelected()` and if the flag is true don't run the code.

Another option would be to check if your `EditText` is empty

```
if (!"".equals(inputView)
{
    // run your code
}
else
{
     // do nothing or display message indicating that nothing is entered
}
```

Whatever you do, you should wrap it in a `try/catch` or do some error checking and take appropriate action(s) if the input is invalid.